# How would I get onclick to activate my code? (I'm super new)

Tags: html

As I said I'm new and I need help please!

Here is my html code:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Western Standerd Time" onclick="paypalwest();" />
<script>
function paypalwest() {
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/334ca3_933382a276684385bef95aa4886cb32e~mv2.gif" onclick="window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3WV26064V0389752R&useraction=commit&xclick_params=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#/checkout/login')" width="150" height="41">
}
</script>
</form>
```

the code doesn't seem to create the paypal image, if you know anything that I'm doing wrong please tell me!

Thanks,
Thomas(Aka Dumbass LOL)

Comment: I'd ask you to clarify what you want, the button will ADD the image?
then when the user clicks on the image it will open a new window?
so the image doesn't appear unless he clicks on that button?

Comment: It looks like you would be better off using a tutorial, because you seem to not have used one: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Comment: I was looking for a code that would have 4 buttons named 'Western Standard Time' Mountain Standard Time' Central Standard Time' Eastern Standard Time' that would make a paypal button appear that corresponds with the shipping cost for where the buyer lives. Then they would click it, than be directed to a checkout page. If someone can make just the "Western" one, I can probably do the rest! Thanks for all of you help, sorry for being so unclear!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

**You need something like this:**

```
    <form>
    <button type="button" class="paypal_button" value="Western Standerd Time" />
    <button type="button" class="paypal_button" value="Mountain Standerd Time" />
    <button type="button" class="paypal_button" value="Central Standerd Time" />
    <button type="button" class="paypal_button" value="Eastern Standerd Time" />

    <script>

      $(document).on('click', '.paypal_button', function() {
        var button = $(this).val();
        If ( button === "Western Standard Time") {
        $(this).after('<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/334ca3_933382a276684385bef95aa4886cb32e~mv2.gif" onclick="window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3WV26064V0389752R&useraction=commit&xclick_params=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#/checkout/login')" width="150" height="41">') 
      }

        If ( button === "Moutain Standard Time") {
        $(this).after('<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/334ca3_933382a276684385bef95aa4886cb32e~mv2.gif" onclick="window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3WV26064V0389752R&useraction=commit&xclick_params=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#/checkout/login')" width="150" height="41">') 
      }

        If ( button === "Central Standard Time") {
        $(this).after('<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/334ca3_933382a276684385bef95aa4886cb32e~mv2.gif" onclick="window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3WV26064V0389752R&useraction=commit&xclick_params=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#/checkout/login')" width="150" height="41">') 
      }

        If ( button === "Eastern Standard Time") {
        $(this).after('<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/334ca3_933382a276684385bef95aa4886cb32e~mv2.gif" onclick="window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=3WV26064V0389752R&useraction=commit&xclick_params=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#/checkout/login')" width="150" height="41">') 
      }

      });
    </script>
    </form>
```

You just have to change the img src parts depending on what you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was looking for a code that would have 4 buttons named 'Western Standard Time' Mountain Standard Time' Central Standard Time' Eastern Standard Time' that would make a paypal button appear that corresponds with the shipping cost for where the buyer lives. Then they would click it, than be directed to a checkout page. If you could make one of them work like just the "Western" one, I can probably do the rest!